# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've this layout xml, named pagina.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descrizione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scelta1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scelta3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scelta1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scelta1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scelta2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scelta3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scelta3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to write the description of the element, but when I assign to a variable the textview element, the emulator crashes. This is the code:

```
public int posizione;
    public String stanza;
    public string[] azioni;
    public int[] vai;
    public XmlPullParser xpp;
    public EditText descr;
    public Button scelta_1, scelta_2, scelta_3;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagina);

        try {
            carica_stanza(posizione);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        descr = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.descrizione);
        scelta_1= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scelta1);
        scelta_2= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scelta2);
        scelta_3= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scelta3);

    }
```

Help me to understand!

Comment: using the `this` keyboard isn't incredibly great style, in my opinion... just get rid of it. it's obvious that you are invoking the `Activity`s `findViewById` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public TextView descr;
// ...
descr = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.descrizione);
```

instead of

```
public EditText descr;
// ...
descr = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.descrizione);
```

You are using `TextView` in xml layout. But you tried to cast this object to `EditText`

What are you going to use? If you want this text to be editable you need to change your component to `EditText` in xml and in your class.

- TextView - just prints text
- EditText - lets you to edit text in program

Comment: + change your descr type to EditText.